# Why do some Rails projects use multiple database.yml files with different extensions (mysql, postgresql etc)?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, gitlab

I've seen this in the source code of [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq)

Managed to run bundle install successfully. But while running the server with `rails s` command an error is shown saying database.yml is missing. My first thought was to rename database.yml.mysql to database.yml but resisted the temptation for monkey patches. I would like to know why this was done and what's the underlying standard behind this convention.

Comment: If you're trying to get gitlab running on your your system why not try the GDK (gitlab development kit). It will do a lot of stuff for you including set up your db stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since database.yml should not be committed to the source code for various reasons (their `.gitignore` explicitly removes database.yml from the repo), maintainers tend to put `.yml.template` as a guide for those would fork the repo. It's not meant to be renamed but rather copied as renaming it would be removing the template.

The multiple extensions (i.e `.mysql`, `.postgres`) are just there for you to know what to copy when you use different databases.

Comment: This is correct. It's there so you can pick whatever DB you want to use. For instance, if you want to use MySQL, you'd copy `database.yml.mysql` to `database.yml`